# limit of $1- \cos(ka)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I am reading a text which says

for $ka \ll 1$:

$1 - \cos(ka) \approx \frac{1}{2}(ka)^{2}$ but I fail to understand why this is so.

Could someone shed light on this?

Comment: Do you know about Taylor/Maclaurin series?

Comment: Or trigonometric identities and the small-angle approximation, $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac x2\approx \frac{x^2}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of its Taylor Series

$$\cos(ka)=1-\frac{(ka)^2}{2!} + \;...$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Yes - thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you know that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin x}}{x} = 1,
$$
then you can expect that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\approx 1$ for small $x$. Thus
$$
1 - \cos x = 2\left( {\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)} \right)^2  \approx 2\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^2  = \frac{{x^2 }}{2}
$$
for small $x$. Now take $x=ka$ with $ka \ll 1$.